# Changing endpoint address on Windows 8 store app WCF service causes "The client and service bindings may be mismatched" exception

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I've written a Windows 8 store app, which is a line of business (LOB) app for my company. The app hits an application-hosted WCF service, using basicHttpBinding. I've had no issue connecting to the service and I am able to retrieve data from the service when the app is running.

My issue arises when I attempt to programatically change the service URI that the app points to. If I change it, to another WCF service which is set up in exactly the same manner (I'm changing it from our UAT environment to our PROD environment) I receive the following exception:

```
Content Type text/xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://server/service.  The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
```

**Edit** - I forgot to mention, this even occurs if I attempt to change the URI that the web service client is already pointing to.

In the midst of attempting to debug this, I noticed that if I debugged the client construction, that the app would connect to the service without issue.

I have also found that if I put any sort of delay in between the client construction and changing the service URI, it works without issue.

This is the construction code - with the delay commented out, it doesn't work, with it uncommented, it works:

```
private async void CreateWebServiceClient()
{
    this.StockLevelsClient = new StockLevelsWebservice.StockLevelsServiceClient();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1));
    this.StockLevelsClient.Endpoint.Address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(_uri);
}
```

It works with the delay, but I'd like to understand why it works...and how to get it working with resorting to dodgy workarounds.

Comment: Isn't there a constructor that takes the endpoint as a parameter? If so, try using that one. And if there isn't, I guess there is something asynchronous going on in that constructor. `await Task.Yield();` might be enough to wait for the async part to complete.

Comment: There is a constructor that takes the endpoint as a parameter, however it gives the same exception. I agree, there is some async part occurring, but I cannot find it. I'll give the `await Task.Yield();` a try too

Comment: @KrisVandermotten tried the Task.Yield()...it's working. It's only a proof of concept app, so I am happy to leave it like that for the moment. Thanks!